# What does the abbreviation “Coisl.” stand for?

Tags: abréviations

When one Googles the phrase “[Paris Bibliothèque Nationale Coisl](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Paris%20Biblioth%C3%A8que%20Nationale%20Coisl&spf=1495568568336),” there is the abbreviation “Coisl.” What does the abbreviation “Coisl.” stand for? Is it for the French equivalent of the English word “collection”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's short for the title (*duc de*) *Coislin*, from the *fonds Coislin*, which is a large collection of Greek manuscripts now in the possession of the French National Library.

See this [page](http://editions.bnf.fr/catalogue-des-manuscrits-grecs-ii-le-fonds-coislin):

> *Le fonds Coislin est la section grecque de la Bibliothèque de manuscrits rassemblée par le chancelier Séguier, transmise par voie d'héritage à son petit-fils, Henri du Cambout, duc de Coislin, évêque de Metz, léguée par celui-ci aux bénédictins de Saint-Germain-des-Prés, puis déposée au cours de la Révolution à la Bibliothèque Nationale, où elle se trouve depuis ce temps.*